# dart: How to save a file?

Tags: file, dart, anchor, angular-dart

I need to save the file that is on my hard drive.

File address: /home/mk/proj1/1.txt

Program address: /home/mk/proj2/

I try to save:

```
new dom.AnchorElement(href: '/home/mk/proj1/1.txt')
 ..setAttribute("download", '1.txt')
 ..click();
```

Displays information about saving, but writes: Failed! No file.

How to save a file?

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a way to save a file in the browser (except perhaps limited support for temporary files)

You can search for JavaScript solutions. They will be quite similar for Dart in the browser.

For example [JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

If you want to store a file on the client machine, you can provide a download link.

See also [How to force a Download File prompt instead of displaying it in-browser with HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825871/how-to-force-a-download-file-prompt-instead-of-displaying-it-in-browser-with-htm)

To provide a download link for data that is available in the browser clients code instead of a server file, you can use a data url.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/29691487/217408